Listing comma usages/distinctions
I have a question concerning the listing comma.
https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/listing#:~:text=Use%20a%20listing%20comma%20in,a%20listing%20comma%20anywhere%20else.&text=Put%20a%20listing%20comma%20before%20and%20or%20or%20only%20if,to%20make%20your%20meaning%20clear.
I'd read this as written in an article online:

He was directing the star in a comedy, they didn't get along, and it led to a disaster at the box-office.

Strictly speaking: should this not need a full stop after the first sentence?
It feels like it needs: but during the production they didn't get along, and it led to a disaster at the box-office.
It doesn't work to my mind like:

He was working alongside his brother, they didn't get along, and the business fell into disrepute.

So my question is: when using a listing comma, with repetition, in these structures shouldn't the context be explicit rather than what feels like skipping information and clear context.
Or is just wrong and needs a full-stop after the first sentence?

No, because you have three full sentences. Subject verb predicate.

It certainly doesn't need "during the production". Explain why you think it needs that. Do you think it's unobvious when they didn't get on? The sequence of events seems very obvious to me and doesn't need any clarification.

Why are you posting the same question twice?

What about this instance?: many things about her are strange; her behaviour and interests seem to be the opposite of how she was before, their pet cat acting aggressive towards her, and her feet no longer fit in her shoes.

doesn't it require: her pet cat has started acting aggressively towards her, and.......I think if it is a list and using a conjunction it should have a sort of stylistic rhythm. That is this distinction between this question and my other posting - this is more a stylistic question.

Commas versus full stop.  The age-old question.  I was taught (long after school) to use periods (full stop) to make the content easier to read.  And, put the "and" at the beginning of the sentence.  When I objected to a conjunction to open the sentence, the person teaching me handed me that day's Wall Street Journal. "Pick any column.  Tell me how many conjunctions you find starting sentences".  I found quite a few. Still, it is purely style. But it communicates. Your choice.
So, yes, I agree:  "He was directing the star in a comedy. They didn't get along. And it led to a disaster at the box-office."
